# Qt : how to implement QDialog StatusBar

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have `QDialog` that is heavily designed with `QDesigner` , I saw on the web that I could add `QStatusBar` with code like this :

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QStatusBar>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QStatusTipEvent>

class Dialog : public QDialog {
public:
Dialog() : QDialog(){
QLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
QTextEdit *te = new QTextEdit;
te->setStatusTip("XXX");
l->addWidget(te);
bar = new QStatusBar;
l->addWidget(bar);
l->setMargin(0);
l->setSpacing(0);
}
private:
QStatusBar *bar;
protected:
bool event(QEvent *e){
if(e->type()==QEvent::StatusTip){
QStatusTipEvent *ev = (QStatusTipEvent*)e;
bar->showMessage(ev->tip());
return true;
}
return QDialog::event(e);
}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
QApplication app(argc, argv);
Dialog dlg;
return dlg.exec();
}
```

Its not even working in my case .. maybe the `QDialog` is already have few layets that holds widget.

My question is can I some how use palceholder in the `QDesigner` or somehow promote widget that place hold the `QStatusbar` class? I don’t know …

What can I do in such case? can I implement new `QStatusbar`?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I presume when you say it doesn't work, that you are not seeing the status bar when you run.

I don't see any way to do this wholly in the designer.  The designer certainly resists the idea of promoting something to a `QStatusBar`.  I suppose you could fool the designer by subclassing `QStatusBar`, and then promoting a `QWidget` to your subclass.

But I don't think we need to go that route just yet.  I think with a few tweaks to the code you have above should help.

In the designer, add a layout, it doesn't matter what kind, at the bottom of your dialog.  I called mine 'StatusBarLayout'.  You can see the layout (the red box that's squished at the bottom).  I removed the bottom margin in the dialog so that the status bar is flush at the bottom.

[image]

Now remove everything in the above code about layout l, and just do this:

```
bar = new QStatusBar(this);
pUI->StatusBarLayout->addWidget(bar);
pUI->textEdit->setStatusTip("XXX");
```

The `textEdit` was something added in the designer.  Now when you run it you should see this:

[image]

I hope that helps

Edit:

You can also set the Status Tips for various widgets in the designer too, so there is no need to do that in the code unless you want to.

Comment: what i did i just placed widget place holder in the designer , and in code i just remove it and replace with the status bar

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a QStatusBar like this:

```
QDialog dialog;
QLayout* layoutWidget = new QVBoxLayout(&dialog);
layoutWidget ->addWidget(new QTextEdit);
QStatusBar* statusBar = new QStatusBar;
layoutWidget ->addWidget(statusBar );
```

Comment: i have problem , all my gui is allready done in the QtDesigner , how can i place the StatusBar with the QDesigner ? can i place Widget placeholder and then create my StatusBar and promote it with the designer?